# When exactly do cookies being stored in browser and attached to HTTP request

Tags: javascript, http, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to figure out when do cookies are being stored (when server responds with `Set-Cookie` header) and also when exactly they are being attached to request. Here is my testing code which I'm trying to understand.
Express backend:

```
router.get('/',  function(req, res, next) {
  var randomNumber=Math.random().toString();
  randomNumber=randomNumber.substring(2,randomNumber.length);
  res.cookie('XSRF-TOKEN',randomNumber, { maxAge: 900000, httpOnly: false });

  if(req.get('X-XSRF-TOKEN') !== req.cookies['XSRF-TOKEN']) {
    return res.status(403).send();
  }

  return  res.send();
});
```

Client side:

```
  private runRequests() {
    for(let i = 0; i < 30; ++i) {
      this.request();
    }
  }

  private request() {
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onload = (e) => {
      console.log("PASSED")
    };
    req.onerror = () => {
      console.log("INVALID")
    };
    req.withCredentials = true;
    req.open("GET", "http://localhost:3000");
    req.setRequestHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", getCookieValue('XSRF-TOKEN'));
    req.send();
  }
```

So what this code does is:

1. On client side it sends 30 parallel requests, each rewritting XSRF-TOKEN cookie to header.
2. On server side it genereates new XSRF token and saves it in request. Additional it compares token value from request's header and cookie and returns 403 it they don't match.

Before running this code i thought that all requests will pass because JS runs on single thread so the whole code in `request` method won't get interrupted, which also means that:

1. `XMLHttpRequest` object is being created "cloning" current cookie context
2. Cookie value is being read and saved as a header (the value at that point should be the same as in document.cookies that were cloned "couple lines ago", because there isn't any code that run in the meantime)

However something weird happens that I'm not able to explain - some requests have different cookie and header value. How is that possible? I don't event know how can i debug it to fully understand what happens under the hood. This example is simplified version of what happens in my angular app and csrf validation. I'd appreciate if someone helps me understand this or give some hints about how/when do browsers set and attach cookie to requests.

Comment: Multiple requests run in parallel, they are not exactly executed by js, but by the browser. If you would use modern fetch API you could await for the request to run them sequentially